# Rails: Creating subfolders in model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, directory, subdirectory

I'm going to have a ton of subclasses, so want to organize them under a subfolder called stream.  I added the following line to the environment.rb so that all classes in the subfolder would be loaded:

```
            Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
...
            config.load_paths += Dir["#{RAILS_ROOT}/app/models/*"].find_all { |f| File.stat(f).directory? }
...
    end
```

I thought this would solve the issue in which by convention the model class is namespaced into an according module. However, when I try to call one of the classes called stream in the stream folder, I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for Stream:Module
    from (irb):28
    from /usr/local/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Here's the model for the parent and one child:

```
class Stream
end

class EventStream < Stream
end
```

Any idea what the issue is?

Comment: Tried this and got the same error: config.load_paths += %W[#{RAILS_ROOT}/app/models/stream].